# 4 cycle weed eater problem

Tags: engine, troubleshooting

Hi I am based in the UK and have a ryobi rbc430sbs which has not been used through winter. I have new fuel and it will only start on full choke. Once running I can move choke to mid position then run position. However when I open throttle in run mode it seems get bogged down then stalls. Any ideas whats happening?

Comment: Most likely a dirty carb. It will need to be disassembled and cleaned.

Comment: Am unsure how to go about this. Will putting 'mechanic in a bottle' fuel additive in with fuel and running it help? Is disassembly and reasonably difficult? Don't know that much about carbs I'm afraid. When I stand weed eater upright for storage a dirty black liquid comes from air filter

Comment: There's probably youtube videos that can help. It's not super complicated, but will require a few tools. If you are at the point of black stuff coming out, I don't think anything less than disassembly and cleaning will work.

Comment: Thanks I believe my carb is a ruixing carburettor h142a or h142r. Do not know what is difference of a ruixing carburettor and can find very little info about this carb online. Will need to look what I can do.

Comment: It looks like that carb is about $15 on amazon, maybe even less on ebay. I'd just buy a new one instead of trying to clean it.

Comment: @R.Bevan, It looks like a pretty typical diaphragm carb: look up tutorials on other 4 cycle diaphragm carbs for reference.

Comment: Have used some "mechanic in a bottle" mixed with fuel was very smoky at first but now starting better. Still sometimes starting on full choke instead if just a burp but us not dying anymore on full revs. Seems to have cleared the carb. At least partially. Will put a little more in next time I refuel. Thanks for all your assistance